# Activity.Current is null in Azure Function with HTTP trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, serilog

We are observing `Activity.Current` always being null locally and when deployed to Azure in our v4.0 Azure Functions running on .NET 6.0. These functions are in-process.

This is problematic as we intend on using the activity's Id to link end-to-end transactions in Application Insights using a custom Serilog enricher (https://oleh-zheleznyak.blogspot.com/2019/08/serilog-with-application-insights.html).

```
// Startup.cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using MyCompany.Contact.Services;
using MyCompany.Data;
using MyCompany.Repository;
using MyCompany.Common.Startup;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(MyCompany.Contact.Startup))]
namespace MyCompany.Contact
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var apiInfo = new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Version = "1.0.0",
                Title = "our api",
                Description = "a description.",
                Contact = new OpenApiContact()
                {
                    Name = "Support",
                    Email = "contact@ourcontact.com"
                }
            };

            new CommonStartupBuilder(builder, apiInfo)
                .ConfigureCommonServices()
                .ConfigureDatabaseServices<MyCompanyContext, IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>()
                .Apply();

            builder.Services.AddScoped<IContactService, ContactService>();
        }
    }
}

// CommonStartupBuilder.cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Configurations;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MyCompany.Common.Caching;
using MyCompany.Common.Email;
using MyCompany.Common.Helpers;
using MyCompany.Common.Logging.Serilog;
using MyCompany.Data;

namespace MyCompany.Common.Startup
{
    public class CommonStartupBuilder
    {
        private readonly IFunctionsHostBuilder _builder;
        private readonly OpenApiInfo _apiInfo;
        private Serilog.ILogger? _logger;

        private bool _applied = false;

        private readonly List<(Action Action, ActionPriority Priority)> _applyActions = new();

        // When apply is called, each configuration option will be applied in the same ordering
        // as defined by the enum values
        private enum ActionPriority
        {
            Services,
            Database
        }

        public bool UseMemoryCache { get; set; } = true;

        public CommonStartupBuilder(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder, OpenApiInfo apiInfo)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(apiInfo);
            _builder = builder;
            _apiInfo = apiInfo;
        }

        public CommonStartupBuilder ConfigureCommonServices()
        {
            _applyActions.Add(new(() => {
                ConfigureLoggingServices();

                var services = _builder.Services;

                services.AddSingleton<IOpenApiConfigurationOptions>(_ =>
                {
                    var options = new OpenApiConfigurationOptions()
                    {
                        Info = _apiInfo,
                        Servers = DefaultOpenApiConfigurationOptions.GetHostNames(),
                        OpenApiVersion = OpenApiVersionType.V2,
                        IncludeRequestingHostName = true,
                        ForceHttps = false,
                        ForceHttp = false,
                    };

                    return options;
                });

                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

                if (UseMemoryCache)
                {
                    services.AddMemoryCache();
                }
            }, ActionPriority.Services));

            return this;
        }

        public CommonStartupBuilder ConfigureDatabaseServices<ContextType, IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWorkImpl>()
            where ContextType : DbContext
            where IUnitOfWork : class
            where UnitOfWorkImpl : class, IUnitOfWork
        {
            _applyActions.Add(new(() =>
            {
                if (_logger == null)
                    throw new Exception($"Expected logging to be initialized.");

                var connectionString = EnvironmentHelper.GetRequiredEnvironmentVariable("DbConnectionString");

                _builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContextType>((options) =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                    options.AddInterceptors(new LogQueryStatsInterceptor(_logger));
                });

                _builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWorkImpl>();
            }, ActionPriority.Database));

            return this;
        }

        public void Apply()
        {
            if (_applied)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Apply() should only be called once.");

            _applied = true;

            foreach (var tuple in _applyActions.OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Priority))
            {
                tuple.Action();
            }

            _logger?.Information($"{_apiInfo.Title} instance started on {System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()}.");
        }

        private void ConfigureLoggingServices()
        {
            var logBuilder = SerilogHelper.GetSerilogConfig(_apiInfo.Title)
                .LogToAppInsights();

#if DEBUG
            logBuilder.WriteTo.Console(theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Literate);
#endif

            _logger = logBuilder.CreateLogger();

            // For use without dependency injection
            Log.Logger = _logger;

            _builder.Services.AddLogging(logBuilder =>
            {
                // Remove the default Application Insights logger so Serilog's sink is the only app insights provider
                // https://github.com/arcus-azure/arcus.observability/blob/main/src/Arcus.Observability.Telemetry.AzureFunctions/Extensions/ILoggerBuilderExtensions.cs
                var appInsightsLogService = logBuilder
                    .Services
                    .FirstOrDefault(service => service.ImplementationType?.Name == "ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

                if (appInsightsLogService == null)
                {
                    _logger.Error("Unable to remove the default Application Insights log provider.");
                }
                else
                {
                    logBuilder.Services.Remove(appInsightsLogService);
                }    
                
                logBuilder.AddSerilog(_logger, true);
            });

            _builder.Services.AddSingleton(_logger);
        }
    }
}

// SerilogHelper.cs
public static class SerilogHelper
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration GetSerilogConfig(string? apiName = null)
    {
        var config = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithOperationId()
            .Destructure.ToMaximumCollectionCount(200)
            .Destructure.ToMaximumDepth(8);

        if (apiName != null)
        {
            config.Enrich.WithProperty("API Name", apiName);
        }

        return config;
    }

    public static LoggerConfiguration LogToAppInsights(this LoggerConfiguration logBuilder, string? appInsightsConnectionString = null)
    {
        appInsightsConnectionString ??= EnvironmentHelper.GetRequiredEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING");

        var telemetryconfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        telemetryconfig.ConnectionString = appInsightsConnectionString;

        logBuilder.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(telemetryconfig, new OperationTelemetryConverter(), LogEventLevel.Verbose);

        return logBuilder;
    }

    private static LoggerConfiguration WithOperationId(this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichConfiguration)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(enrichConfiguration);
        return enrichConfiguration.With<OperationIdEnricher>();
    }
}

// Example of one of our Functions
[FunctionName("UpdateContact")]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "Contact" })]
[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", bodyType: typeof(UpdateFunction), Description = "Update Contact", Required = true)]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", bodyType: typeof(UpdateFunctionResponse), Description = "The OK response")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "contact/update")] HttpRequest req, ILogger logger)
{
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "test log info");
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, "test log warning");
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "test log info2");
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Warning, "test log warning2");

    return new OkObjectResult(new { Ok = "Ok" });
}

// Function project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyCompany.DAL\MyCompany.Repository\MyCompany.Repository.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyCompany.Utilities\MyCompany.Common\MyCompany.Common.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyCompany.Contact.Models\MyCompany.Contact.Models.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyCompany.Contact.Services\MyCompany.Contact.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


// Common library project file
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.28.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

We have tried:

1. Downgrading System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource to version 4.6.0 by adding
   `<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="4.6.0" />`
   to our project files with no luck.
2. The solution included in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7278
3. The enricher available at https://observability.arcus-azure.net but it seems this package uses Activity.Current as well.

We are expecting Activity.Current to be non-null.